# SQL Server Creating a temp table for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have this query:

```
DECLARE 
@ProjectID int = 3,
@Year int = 2010,
@MeterTypeID int = 1,
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime

SET @StartDate = '07/01/' + CAST(@Year as VARCHAR)
SET @EndDate = '06/30/' + CAST(@Year+1 as VARCHAR)

SELECT  tblMEP_Sites.Name AS SiteName, convert(varchar(10),BillingMonth ,101) AS BillingMonth, SUM(Consumption) AS Consumption
FROM tblMEP_Projects

JOIN tblMEP_Sites
ON tblMEP_Projects.ID = tblMEP_Sites.ProjectID

JOIN tblMEP_Meters
ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID

JOIN tblMEP_MonthlyData
ON tblMEP_MonthlyData.MeterID = tblMEP_Meters.ID

JOIN tblMEP_CustomerAccounts
ON tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.ID = tblMEP_Meters.CustomerAccountID

JOIN tblMEP_UtilityCompanies
ON tblMEP_UtilityCompanies.ID = tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.UtilityCompanyID

JOIN tblMEP_MeterTypes
ON tblMEP_UtilityCompanies.UtilityTypeID = tblMEP_MeterTypes.ID

WHERE tblMEP_Projects.ID = @ProjectID
AND tblMEP_MonthlyData.BillingMonth Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND tbLMEP_MeterTypes.ID = @MeterTypeID
GROUP BY BillingMonth, tblMEP_Sites.Name
ORDER BY month(BillingMonth)
```

I just want store it in a temp table so that I can do something with it. It would be great if anybody can just include the syntax for creating a temp table in SQL Server.

I tried different ways but I was lost and did not get the result I want.

Comment: try SELECT INTO statement

Comment: this is automatic insert to a temptable without actually creating the temp table structure. your choice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to just create a temp table inside the query that will allow you to do something with the results that you deposit into it you can do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
Item 1 VARCHAR(200)
, Item 2 VARCHAR(200)
, ...
, Item n VARCHAR(500)
)
```

On the top of your query and then do an

```
INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT
FROM
(...)
```

Comment: Correct on @ vs. # , but INCORRECT on tempdb,  BOTH temp tables and table variables get stored in tempdb.  This myth of table variables has been going on for years, but it is simply not true.  Google several reputable websites,  BOTH absolutely writes to disk.

Comment: @TomStickel - Not anymore, you can create in-memory tables now for better performance without writing to disk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization.

Answer (score 9):

Like this.  Make sure you drop the temp table (at the end of the code block, after you're done with it) or it will error on subsequent runs.

```
SELECT  
    tblMEP_Sites.Name AS SiteName, 
    convert(varchar(10),BillingMonth ,101) AS BillingMonth, 
    SUM(Consumption) AS Consumption
INTO 
    #MyTempTable
FROM 
    tblMEP_Projects
    JOIN tblMEP_Sites
        ON tblMEP_Projects.ID = tblMEP_Sites.ProjectID
    JOIN tblMEP_Meters
        ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID
    JOIN tblMEP_MonthlyData
        ON tblMEP_MonthlyData.MeterID = tblMEP_Meters.ID
    JOIN tblMEP_CustomerAccounts
        ON tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.ID = tblMEP_Meters.CustomerAccountID
    JOIN tblMEP_UtilityCompanies
        ON tblMEP_UtilityCompanies.ID = tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.UtilityCompanyID
    JOIN tblMEP_MeterTypes
        ON tblMEP_UtilityCompanies.UtilityTypeID = tblMEP_MeterTypes.ID
WHERE 
    tblMEP_Projects.ID = @ProjectID
    AND tblMEP_MonthlyData.BillingMonth Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND tbLMEP_MeterTypes.ID = @MeterTypeID
GROUP BY 
    BillingMonth, tblMEP_Sites.Name

DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to query the results from a temporary table inside the same query, you can use # temp tables, or @ table variables (I personally prefer @), for querying outside of the scope you would either want to use ## global temp tables or create a new table with the results.

```
DECLARE 
@ProjectID int = 3,
@Year int = 2010,
@MeterTypeID int = 1,
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime

SET @StartDate = '07/01/' + CAST(@Year as VARCHAR)
SET @EndDate = '06/30/' + CAST(@Year+1 as VARCHAR)

DECLARE @MyTempTable TABLE (SiteName varchar(50), BillingMonth varchar(10), Consumption float)

INSERT INTO @MyTempTable (SiteName, BillingMonth, Consumption)
SELECT  tblMEP_Sites.Name AS SiteName, convert(varchar(10),BillingMonth ,101) AS BillingMonth, SUM(Consumption) AS Consumption
FROM tblMEP_Projects
```

Comment: `@MyTempTable` will create variable, while `#` will create temp table in `tempdb`

Comment: @Paritosh true, given the OP didn't know the syntax of a temp table, I assumed the question meant 'I need to temporarily store the results in a table structure that I can query against' (in which case # or @ will work)

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE #MyTempTable TABLE (SiteName varchar(50), BillingMonth varchar(10), Consumption float)

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable (SiteName, BillingMonth, Consumption)
SELECT  tblMEP_Sites.Name AS SiteName, convert(varchar(10),BillingMonth ,101) AS BillingMonth, SUM(Consumption) AS Consumption
FROM tblMEP_Projects.......  --your joining statements
```

Here, `#` - use this to create table inside `tempdb`
`@` - use this to create table as variable.

Comment: SQL reports bad syntax `DECLARE #MyTempTable TABLE ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a temp table after check exist table.You can use the following code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.#temptable
CREATE TABLE #temptable
  (
   SiteName             NVARCHAR(50),
   BillingMonth         varchar(10),
   Consumption          INT,
  )
```

After creating the temporary table, you can insert data into this table as a regular table:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT COLUMN1,...
FROM
(...)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

The SELECT statement is used to select data from a temp table.

```
SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

you can manually remove the temporary table by using the DROP TABLE statement:

```
DROP TABLE #temptable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable (SiteName varchar(50), BillingMonth varchar(10), Consumption float)

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable (SiteName, BillingMonth, Consumption)
SELECT  tblMEP_Sites.Name AS SiteName, convert(varchar(10),BillingMonth ,101)
AS BillingMonth, SUM(Consumption) AS Consumption
FROM tblMEP_Projects.......
```